# Object animator display based on width dimensions

Tags: android, animation

Please guide how to set Objectanimator dimension dynamically from device width.

Fragment replace code with animation

```
   Fragment f = ... //defined elsewhere
   FragmentManager fm1 = getFragmentManager()    
   FragmentTransaction ft1 = fm1.beginTransaction();

   ft1.setCustomAnimations(R.animator.slide_in_left,
                        R.animator.slide_out_right);
    ft1.replace(R.id.content_layout, f)
           .addToBackStack(null)
           .commit();
```

slide_in_left.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <set>
  <objectAnimator  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:propertyName="x" 
      android:valueType="floatType"
      android:valueFrom="-800"
      android:valueTo="0" 
      android:duration="500" />
 </set>
```

how I am supposed to set the "valueFrom", and "valueTo" value based on device width,Please guide me it is possible to achieve this method or suggest some other ideas.

Comment: override `Animator Fragment#onCreateAnimator(int transit, boolean enter, int nextAnim)`

Comment: suggest anyexample link for above method

Comment: this is the link: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#onCreateAnimator(int,%20boolean,%20int)